# Quota on filesystem mounted via SSHFS

Tags: xfs, quota, sshfs

On client C, a directory from server S is mounted via SSHFS (authenticated as user U). The relevant filesystem on S has a quota set. How can a user on C see her quota? The `quota` command run on C displays nothing. Is there a way to make it work? S uses XFS, if that makes any difference.

Ideas for workarounds:

- SSH into S as U and run the `quota` command there. Problem is, U should not be allowed shell access to S. This is currently implemented via `ForceCommand internal-sftp` in a `Match` block in `sshd_config`. We would have to write a wrapper script to allow `sftp-server` and `quota`.
- Let a CRON job on S regularly run `quota` for each user and put the result in a file in their home directory, e.g., `~/.quota`. Pro: SSHD config stays tidy; con: more load on the server, no real-time info for users.